# spring kafka consumer with circuit breaker functionality using Resilience4j library

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, resilience4j

I am trying to implement the spring kafka consumers which needs to be paused after a certain exception while processing the event (ex: while storing the event info to DB, DB is down).

How do we handle this scenario using Resilience4j circuit breaker approach with spring boot - 2.3.8 (spring kafka)

Looking for some examples on the consumer to pause and resume also.

```
@Component
public class CircuitBreakerManager {

    private CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    public CircuitBreakerManager() {
        CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .slidingWindowType(CircuitBreakerConfig.SlidingWindowType.COUNT_BASED)
                .enableAutomaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpen()
                .minimumNumberOfCalls(5)
                .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(3)
                .slidingWindowSize(10)
                .failureRateThreshold(50)
                .slowCallRateThreshold(60.0f)
                .slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                .build();
        CircuitBreakerRegistry registry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(circuitBreakerConfig);
        this.circuitBreaker = registry.circuitBreaker("serialization_exception");
        this.circuitBreaker.getEventPublisher().onStateTransition(this::onStateChange);
    }

    private void onStateChange(CircuitBreakerOnStateTransitionEvent circuitBreakerEvent) {
        CircuitBreaker.State toState = circuitBreakerEvent.getStateTransition()
                .getToState();
        System.out.println("Change in Circuit Breaker state " + toState);
        switch (toState) {
            case OPEN:
                    kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("my_listener_id").stop();
                break;
            case CLOSED:
                break;
            case HALF_OPEN:
                kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("my_listener_id").start();
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

At kafka listerner Just wanted to catch the parse error.if we get more than 5 parsing errors , the listener needs to be stopped. But i am not sure how the circuit breaker will get triggered.

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = RESILIENCE4J_INSTANCE_NAME)
    private Event getParsedEvent(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord) {
        Event event = getEvent(consumerRecord);
        
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(event)) {
                
                throw new RuntimeException("Serialization Exception occurred");
            }
        }
        return event;
    }
```

Comment: If you just wish to pause the consumption, then you can also do that by not acknowledging the offset when DB is down. This way the there will be no extra poll but if it reaches the total session timeout, it might rebalancing

Comment: Thank You Suraj for your input. It seems  circuit breaker approach is more handy and cleaner to pass the listener some time.

Answer (score 0):

See [Pausing and Resuming Listener Containers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#pause-resume).

Note that pause won't take effect until all the records returned from the current poll have been processed (or an exception is thrown by the listener, as long as the default error handler is in place).

Comment: Hi Gary.. Thank you!! I am coming up with the code. will up in the actual post.

Comment: Hi Gary.. just wanted to check with you, how can i start and stop listener within the application considering circuit breaker pattern?  I have added the code, but not sure how we can trigger it.

Comment: I am not familiar with resilience4j; you are using the endpoint registry correctly; however, using stop/start instead of pause/resume will completely stop the container and have the partitions assigned to another instance (if present). pausing leaves the partition assignment as-is but prevents the reception of any more records (until resumed).

Comment: Thanks Gary for your response. keeping the circuit breaker aside, how the pause and resume will work in batch mode ?

Comment: The same as record mode, pause will take effect after the current batch is completed or an exception is thrown.

Comment: Hi Gary, quick question is , can we have a listener as one thread and another thread component to hold the status of the listener in single spring boot application ?

Comment: I mean  can we have a listener as one thread and another thread component to hold the status of the listener (to change status to pass/resume) in single spring boot application ?

Comment: Yes, the pause/resume can be done on any thread; you should not, generally, however, hand off processing of a record from the listener thread to another thread.

Comment: Do you have some sample reference code on this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with; the listener is invoked by the container on the consumer thread(s), the endpoint registry can be used anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I think i got what you mentioned in https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#pause-resume.  But got one more question : How this works in concurrent consumers. how do we get the consumer id in this scenario ?

Comment: All consumers in a container will be paused when you pause the container.